# Call a func from another class in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to call a function which is coded on another class.
So far I have made a struct on the file *structs.swift* for my data:

```
struct defValues {
    let defCityName: String
    let loadImages: Bool

    init(defCity: String, loadImgs: Bool){
        self.defCityName = defCity
        self.loadImages = loadImgs
    }

}
```

I have made the file *Defaults.swift* containing:

```
import Foundation

class DefaultsSet {

    let cityKey: String = "default_city"
    let loadKey: String = "load_imgs"

    func read() -> defValues {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if let name = defaults.stringForKey(cityKey){
            print(name)
            let valuesToReturn = defValues(defCity: name, loadImgs: true)
            return valuesToReturn
        }
        else {
            let valuesToReturn = defValues(defCity: "No default city set", loadImgs: true)
            return valuesToReturn
        }
    }

    func write(city: String, load: Bool){
        let def = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        def.setObject(city, forKey: cityKey)
        def.setBool(load, forKey: loadKey)
    }

}
```

in which I have the two functions read, write to read and write data with NSUsersDefault respectively.
On my main ViewController I can read data with:

```
let loadeddata: defValues = DefaultsSet().read()
if loadeddata.defCityName == "No default city set" {
    defaultCity = "London"
}
else {
    defaultCity = loadeddata.defCityName
    defaultLoad = loadeddata.loadImages

}
```

But when I try to write data it gives me error. I use this code:

```
@IBOutlet var settingsTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var defaultCityName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var loadImgs: UISwitch!

var switchState: Bool = true

@IBAction func switchChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.on{
        switchState = true
        print(switchState)
    }else   {
        switchState = false
        print(switchState)
    }
}

@IBAction func saveSettings(sender: UIButton) {
    DefaultsSet.write(defaultCityName.text, switchState)
}
```

Comment: I just added () and worked. I've tried many times but it didn't. My new *working* code is:      `@IBAction func saveSettings(sender: UIButton) {
        DefaultsSet().write(defaultCityName.text!, load: switchState)
    }`

Comment: Glad that you resolved your own problem. For future reference though, highlight the error line and add the error message. "It doesn't work" is too vague for us to help you.

Comment: In Swift, the name of structs should be capitalized so I'd rename `defValues` to `DefValues`. It's not critical, but it looks much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an instance of the `DefaultsSet` class

In the view controller add this line on the class level

```
var setOfDefaults = DefaultsSet()
```

Then read

```
let loadeddata = setOfDefaults.read()
```

and write

```
setOfDefaults.write(defaultCityName.text, switchState)
```

The variable name `setOfDefaults` is on purpose to see the difference.

Or make the functions class functions and the variables static variables and call the functions on the class (without parentheses)

Comment: Thank you for your comments and your help. I appreciate it. I'm new in this world. @vadian I like your solution. I'm gonna change the code :)

Comment: Do you really need an instance? I would make the vars and the functions static which removes the need for an instance. But in that case, do you even need a class - I'd just use a struct with static methods.

Comment: @Abizern I'd also prefer a static class or struct, but I wanted to provide a solution with the least code changes.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, it seems you either need to make the `write` method a class method (just prefix it with `class`) or you need to call it on an instance of `DefaultsSet`: `DefaultsSet().write(defaultCityName.text, switchState)`.

Another issue I found is that you also need to unwrapp the value of the textField. Your `write` method takes as parameters a `String` and a `Bool`, but the value of `defaultCityName.text` is an optional, so `String?`. This results in a compiler error.

You can try something like this:

```
@IBAction func saveSettings(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let text = defaultCityName.text else {
         // the text is empty - nothing to save
         return
    }

    DefaultsSet.write(text, switchState)
}
```

This code should now compile and let you call your method.

Let me know if it helped you solve the problem

Comment: @catalinaturlea  I used this:      `@IBAction func saveSettings(sender: UIButton) {
        if defaultCityName.text?.isEmpty == false{
            let citySaved = defaultCityName.text!
            setOfDefaults.write(citySaved, load: switchState)
            defaultCityName.text = ""
            defaultCityName.placeholder = "Saved: \(citySaved)!"
        }
        else {
            setOfDefaults.write("No default city set", load: switchState)
            defaultCityName.text = ""
            defaultCityName.placeholder = "No default city set!"
        }
    }`